# Excel IF statement Comparing text with number

Tags: excel-formula

I was using `IF` statement to group some numbers together.
In column `A` I have numeric and text values.

```
  A   B
1 s   =IF(A1>200,2345,"ad")
```

If I do this then the `B1` returns `2345`.

How does Excel compare string values with number values?

Answer (score 11):

For the Excel compare operators (e.g. `<`, `=`, `>`), number values are less than text values which are less than logical values. You can use the `VALUE` function to convert text values to number values for number comparisons. You can use the `TEXT` function to convert number values to text values for text comparison.

Comment: Where is this documented?

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate a letter to both the formula (string) and the number and excel will be able to compare them. I was having the same problem when comparing the result of an index match formula with a number and this solved it easily.

Example:

String:

```
=CONCATENATE("Q",Result from formula)
```

Number:

```
=CONCATENATE("Q",Number)
```

IF string=number should work now.